# Updating variable through input box using React using State Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement a React script where I update a variable and make it equal to the input but I'm not able to update it. (Input is a 10 digit number )

Here is my script-

```
const [MeetingIDi, setMeetingIDi] = useState('')
 const handleUserInputChange = (e) =>
      {
        setMeetingIDi(e.target.name);
        fetchTrans()
      };

return <RightWrapper>
        <Header>
          <Button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete Transcription</Button>
          <Button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</Button>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Meeting ID" defaultValue="Hello!" onChange={handleUserInputChange}/>
        </Header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the input `value` attribute if you want an input to change a state varible.

```
const handleUserInputChange = (e) => {
    setMeetingIDi(e.target.value)
    //...
}
```

```
<input type='text'
placeholder='Meeting ID'
value={MeetingIDi}
onChange={handleUserInputChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

`e.target.name` will assign the `name` of the input field to the `state`. If you want to assign the `value` of the input field to the the state then you have to use `e.target.value` in your function.

```
const handleUserInputChange = (e) => {
  setMeetingIDi(e.target.value);
  fetchTrans()
}
```